# How to put Google Voice into Hands Free mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, google-now, hands-free

Google Voice can be set to provide voice ptompts Always or only on Hands Free mode.

I want the latter.

But how do i put my s7 into Hands Free mode?